# invoke registered eventhandlers on routedevents with reflection in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection

I want to invoke all registered RoutedEvent handlers of a FrameworkElement (e.g. a MouseLeftButtonUp or a MouseMove of a ContentControl/Canvas/...). In my case, i got a reference to that object and I know which Event should be invoked. But after trying several hours with reflection I am asking myself if this is even possible???

I thought doing something like this:

```
var eventInfo = contentControl.GetType().GetEvent("MouseLeftButtonUp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var getInvocationListMethod = eventInfo.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("GetInvocationList", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
Delegate[] delegates = (Delegate[])getInvocationListMethod.Invoke(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, null);
foreach (var handler in delegates)
{
    handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[] { contentControl, new EventArgs()});
}
```

this actually always throws an exception with Message "Object does not match target type.". So has anybody a clue on this?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: Most probably, these events are implemented with add/remove accessors rather than a dedicated for event field with delegate. This is why there is no invocation list - it is perhaps stored somewhere else because it is a routed event. See also [this article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier than you might think.
To invoke an event once you have the `EventInfo` object you can simply use `evtInfo.GetRaiseMethod(true).Invoke(...)`

But the reason your code fails is because the [ContentControl.MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx) event uses the [MouseButtonEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventhandler.aspx) delegate which expects a `MouseButtonEventArgs` argument.

So, to make your example work, your could try the following code:

```
var eventInfo = contentControl.GetType().GetEvent("MouseLeftButtonUp", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var raise = eventInfo.GetRaiseMethod(true);
raise.Invoke(contentControl, new object[] { contentControl, new MouseButtonEventArgs(null, 0, MouseButton.Left) });
```

I am not sure whether the `MouseButtonEventArgs` constructor allows a null MouseDevice, alternatively your could leave the argument as null altogether:

```
raise.Invoke(contentControl, new object[] { contentControl, null });
```